# how to make an input number that doesn't reset when re-opened/refreshed?

Tags: html, input

How do I make an input() that doesn't reset when re-opened/refreshed?

So I used this code:

```
<button onclick="stepupfunction()"> PRESS ME </button>
<input id="score" type="number" value="0" readonly=true;>

<script>
function stepupfunction() {
document.getElementById("score").stepUp(1);
}
</script>
```

But each time I refresh or re-open the page, the input always reset to 0, how to make it doesn't reset when refreshed or re-opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take the value from somewhere. I use [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) to do this.

**EDITED**

```
<button onclick="stepupfunction()"> PRESS ME </button>
<input id="score" type="text" value="0" readonly=true;>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="store+json2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addListener('onLoad', function documentLoaded(e) {
        document.getElementById("score").value = store.get('putAKeyHere') || 0;
    })
    function stepupfunction() {
        document.getElementById("score").stepUp(1);
        store.set('putAKeyHere',document.getElementById("score").value)
    }
</script>
```